# Registration issues using module reveal pattern

Tags: javascript, revealing-module-pattern

I'm builing a simples VanillaJS library that toggle things to learn reveal module pattern.

I have to register toggle actions like this `toggler('.tab').setToggleAction(onToggle).init();`.

When I registered for instance :
`toggler('.tab').setToggleAction(onToggle).init();`
`toggler('.accordion-title').setToggleAction(onToggleAccordion).init();`

It replaced the `onToggle` callback function of `toggler('.tab')` with the `onToggleAccordion` toggle action.

Then I had to do some adjustments in order to preserve the variable scope for each toggler registration.

I think there is something wrong with that, so much functions returning functions. There is a better approach to this situation?

```js
var toggler = function(selector) {
  return (function() {
    var toggles = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    var _toggleContent = function(toggleFunction) {
      return function() {
        if (toggleFunction) {
          return (toggleFunction.bind(this))();
        }

        throw 'You must set a callback for toggler [' + selector + ']';
      }
    };

    return {
      init: function() {
        for (var x = 0; x < toggles.length; x++) {
          toggles[x].addEventListener('click', _toggleContent(toggleFunction));
        }

        return this;
      },
      setToggleAction: function(callback) {
        toggleFunction = callback;
        return this;
      }
    };
  })();
};

var onToggle = function() {
  alert('You toggled ' + this.id)
  this.parentElement.querySelector('.element-to-be-toggled').classList.toggle('expanded');
};

toggler('.tab').setToggleAction(onToggle).init();
```

```css
.tab {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  list-style: none;
}

.element-to-be-toggled {
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.element-to-be-toggled.expanded {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3 id="tab1" class="tab">Tab1 (click here)</h3>
    <div class="weird-content">
      <ul>
        <li>
          Blah blah
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="element-to-be-toggled">
            Toggler ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, adipisci velit vitae, distinctio ipsum non! Facere iure, rerum non. Quibusdam.
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3 id="tab2" class="tab">Tab2 (click here)</h3>
    <div class="weird-content34234">
      <ul>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
          <div class="element-to-be-toggled">
            Toggler ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, adipisci velit vitae, distinctio ipsum non! Facere iure, rerum non. Quibusdam.
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam, eligendi.
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3 id="tab3" class="tab">Tab3 (click here)</h3>
    <div class="element-to-be-toggled">
      Toggler ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, adipisci velit vitae, distinctio ipsum non! Facere iure, rerum non. Quibusdam.
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating things. You dont need an IIFE etc., just do this:

```
 function toggler(selector){
   const el = document.querySelector(selector);
   let handler = () => { throw "Please add a handler!";};

   return {
     setToggleAction(h){ 
        handler = h; 
        return this;
     },
     init(){
       el.addEventListener("click", (e) => handler(e));
       return this;
     }
  };
}
```

But i personally prefer OOP over closuring in such cases:

```
 class Toggler {
   constructor(selector){
    this.handler =  () => { throw "Set the handler!"; };
    this.el = document.querySelector(selector);
  }

  init(){
    this.el.addEventListener("click", (e) => this.handler(e));
    return this;
  }

  setToggleAction(handler){
    this.handler = handler;
    return this;
  }
}
```